# JRuby Rails 3.1.6 deploy WAR on Tomcat 7 in subdirectory (redirects and links don't use the subdirectory)

Tags: tomcat, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jruby, rails-routing

I have an JRuby on Rails 3.1.6 application and want to deploy it on a Tomcat 7 as WAR file. To generate the war I use warbler.

I can deploy the application to the server and all is running. But the links generated or a redirect form devise to `/users/sign_in` dont work because the context path is ignored.

I tried to set the relative url root with:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/foo'
```

But the method was not found. (Also tried the ENV variable for this, but nothing happened)

I tried to use `scope '/foo'` in my `routes.rb` but this doesn't work either.

I also tried to add this in my `config.ru`

```
map '/foo' do
  run Foo::Application
end
```

But the `config.ru` files seams not to be included in the WAR file or used in any way.

I can't generate a VirtualHost or anything in tomcat, I have only the rights to deploy the application as WAR file. Is there any way to tell the rails application that it runs under a given subdirectory (context path) so it adds this to all generated links, redirects, etc., that works within Rails 3.1.6?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the exact same setup you have described.  Can you please give me some pointers on how you got your setup working (aside from the subdirectory issue)?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355565/gotchas-for-deploying-jruby-on-rails-3-2-on-tomcat7-packaged-with-warbler

Comment: thank you in advance if you have time (sorry, but stack overflow truncated my previous comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a **Devise** thing, have you checked how it's issuing the redirect ?
It should have worked, assuming you do something like the following from an action :

```
def index
  redirect_to :action => "hello"
end
```

*jruby-rack* (gets included when you `warble`) correctly handles cases when an application is running within a servlet context path different than **/**. I suggest to reverse the "hacks" you did trying to make things work and look into the code that redirected you ... e.g. code such as `redirect_to "/home/goodbye"` won't "work" (prefix the context path) as its assumed to be a complete URL path.

As for the `config.ru` for a Rails application Warbler does not copy it - thus it can distinguish a Rails from a plain Rack application (as *jruby-rack* does more hooks into Rails to provide a seamless experience with servlet containers such as Tomcat).