# Gotchas for deploying jRuby on Rails 3.2 on Tomcat7 packaged with Warbler

Tags: tomcat7, jrubyonrails, warbler

I'm experiencing some weird behaviours trying to deploying a jRuby on Rails (3.2) app on Tomcat7 using Warbler (`warble executable war`).  And wanted to find out if they are normal or am I just doing some newbie mistake.

1. The app deploys fine when the WAR file is exploded, but there are loading issues when trying to deploy from just the WAR file.  What type of "typical" newbie mistakes generally causes this?
2. Running `java -jar app.war -S rake -T` is incredibly slow on Windows (~1min30sec-2min30sec), but on Linux it is fine (~10-15sec).  Is this a normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have loading issues before and after some research,
I've changed

securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom with securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom

in  $JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/java.security file and it load within a reasoanble time.

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, we gave up and decided to just explode it ourselves, but I'll give it a try the next time I try this.